# How to make drop down content with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a similar function on my blog like on http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/04/groupon-acquires-software-devlopment-startup-obtiva/ when you press on author. It is a drop down made with javascript. Anybody can help with a similar javascript as I was trying different implementations for the whole night with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic way to do is just using jquery. Check it from [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find what you are referring to, so I just guess…

First, create the dropdown using [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement)("[select](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)"). Next, create as many "option" elements as you like and add them to the "select" element. Last, add the "select" element into the DOM and you are done.